# Determining when two boolean functions are equivalent?

Tags: model-checking, sat, ctl, nuxmv

**Problem**
Given two boolean functions `f1(a,b)` and `f2(a,b,c)` with a,b and c booleans, I'd like to know if there exists a value of c such that for any combinations of a et b `f1(a,b)=f2(a,b,c)`.

For example if `f1(a,b)=a AND b` and `f2(a,b,c)=a AND b AND c`, we can *see* that `f1=f2` when `c=1`. However, if `f1(a,b)=a OR b` and `f2(a,b,c)=a AND b AND c`, no value of c holds for `f1=f2`.

**Failed approach**
I tried to use model checking, with a trivial model implemented in nuXmv,  to answer this question with a CTL specification such as `EF ( AG ( (a & b) = (a & b & c)))` but it fails. 
Obviously, it works fine with the specification `AG ( c=true -> (a & b = a & b & c))` but it requires to have 2^n specifications (with n being the difference between the number of variables between the two functions).

What is the best way/tool/approach in your opinion to tackle the issue.

Thanks for pointing to the right direction.

Comment: The question title says *"Determining **if** two Boolean functions are equivalent?"*, but the question body is more like *"Determining **when** two Boolean functions are equivalent?"*. Can you clarify?

Comment: Yes you are correct - I want to know when the two functions are equivalent (if they can be equivalent). I am updating the question title.

Answer (score 1):

If I were using `nuXmv` for this task, I would write the following model

```
MODULE main
VAR
    a : boolean;
    b : boolean;
    c : boolean;

CTLSPEC ((a & b) = (a & b & c));
```

and then incrementally remove from the state space all those states for which the property is falsified. For example, given this:

```
nuXmv > reset; read_model -i test.smv ; go ; check_property 
-- specification (a & b) = ((a & b) & c)  is false
-- as demonstrated by the following execution sequence
Trace Description: CTL Counterexample 
Trace Type: Counterexample 
  -> State: 1.1 <-
    a = TRUE
    b = TRUE
    c = FALSE
```

I would then write this (because `c` is the only watched variable):

```
MODULE main
VAR
    a : boolean;
    b : boolean;
    c : boolean;
INVAR
    c != FALSE;

CTLSPEC ((a & b) = (a & b & c));
```

which would actually allow for the iterative-refinement search to stop because now the property is true under all possible evaluations of `a` and `b`:

```
nuXmv > reset; read_model -i test.smv ; go ; check_property
-- specification (a & b) = ((a & b) & c)  is true
```

Now, this does not appear to be the ideal solution because it requires parsing the output of `nuXmv` and correspondingly modify the original file. Compared to your approach, that checks all possible assignments of values, this method enumerates only those assignments which make the formula unsatisfiable. Still, there could be exponentially many counter-examples so it is not that much of an improvement.

---

One alternative is to use *SMT* with **universal quantification** over an *EUF* formula including the definitions of `f1` and `f2`, where the only free variable is `c`:

```
(define-fun f1 ((a Bool) (b Bool)) Bool
               (and a b)
)
(define-fun f2 ((a Bool) (b Bool) (c Bool)) Bool
               (and a b c)
)
(declare-fun c () Bool)

(assert (forall
            ((a Bool) (b Bool))
            (=
                (f1 a b)
                (f2 a b c)
            )
))

(check-sat)
(get-model)
```

This gives you the following model with the *SMT* solver `z3`:

```
~$ z3 test3.smt2 
sat
(model 
  (define-fun c () Bool
    true)
)
```

If you would like to know **all** possible values of `c` for which `f1 = f2`, then your best shot is to implement an **incremental allsat** search on top of `z3` (see: plenty of Q/A here on stackoverflow on the topic).

Comment: thanks a lot, the SMT approach is exactly what i was looking for!